# Split file in excel for avoiding row limit

Tags: excel, vba, split, row

I have a .all file that exceeds the limit of 1048576 rows imposed by excel.

Im using this code:

```
Sub open()
book1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
file1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("ALL Files (*.all), *.all")
Worksheets("res").Range("K1").Value = file1
Workbooks.OpenText file1, origin:=xlWindows, startrow:=1, DataType:=xlTextFormat
del = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveSheet.Copy before:=Workbooks(book1).Sheets(1)
Workbooks(del).Close False
Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = "acti"
End Sub
```

But this code doesent work for long files because this limit. My idea is to copy the original .all file, then split this copy in files limited to 1048576 rows, copy each of this splited files in an individual Sheet and finally revome this copies.

Im pretty new in vba...any help to write the code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Create a new sheet instead of creating a new excel file itself, as the limit is on the sheet and not on the excel file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split a file into separate parts using the code below.

```
Public Sub Split_wb()

Dim i As Integer, arr As Variant, wb As Variant, ws_source As Worksheet

Set ws_source = ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To 5
    arr = ws_source.Range("A" & i * 1000 - 999 & ":T" & i * 1000)

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
    Set arr = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Also, I'd recommend looking into using Access or SQL Server, if Excel can't handle your demands.